# Is there any shortcuts in getting an H-infinity norm of a matrix expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

One of the past exam problems I was solving, has this in its official solution:
[image]

Usually, to calculate the $H_{\infty}$ norm of any matrix expression $M$ I'd first calculate the eigenvalues of $MM^*$, then take the largest one and square root it to get the largest singular value of $M$ which is its $H_{\infty}$ norm.

I was wondering, what kind of voodoo magic let's them solve the thing in one line, instead of conducting the thought process I have?

EDIT: Also, in this case $G$ is actually a transfer function $G(s)$.

Comment: Is $G$ a matrix (function)? If so, what are exactly $-1$ and $1$ in the expression?

Comment: $G$ is a scalar function in this case. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this calculation comes from two parts. First, the eigenvalue of $aa^T$, where $a$ is $n\times 1$ vector, is just $\|a\|_2^2=a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2$ and (n-1) $0$s(This is because when $b$ is perpendicular to $a$, $a a^T b=0$. Thus the eigenvector is just $a$, thus $aa^Ta=a\|a\|_2^2$.) Secondly, if we want to compute eigenvector of $(ab^T)(ab^T)^T=ab^Tba^T$,simply note that $b^Tb=\|b\|_2^2$. Thus
$$\|ab^T\|_{H\infty}=\sqrt{\max spec(ab^Tba^T)}=\sqrt{\|b\|_2^2\max spec aa^T}=\|a\|_2\|b\|_2.$$
In this case
$$\left\|\begin{bmatrix}1& -1\end{bmatrix}(1+G)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ G \end{bmatrix}\right\|_{H\infty}=(1+G)^{-1}\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}\sqrt{1^2+G^2}\le\sqrt{2}$$